# Maximum difference between final and initial sum

Tags: java, python, algorithm

I am new to programming and having trouble solving one task. I have several input example. First line contains two numbers m (number of digits on paper, 1<m<1000) and h (limit on the number of operations, 1<h<1000). I have the opportunity, no more than h times, to take any number from a piece of paper (means m), then paint over one of the old digits, and write a new arbitrary digit in its place. By what maximum value can I be able to increase the sum of all the numbers on the piece of paper?

First example:

Input:

5 2 //m and h

1 3 1 4 5   //m = 5, so I can add 5 arbitrary numbers and h=2, so I can change 2 numbers

Output:

16   // cause I changed 1 and 1 to 9 and 9, so the difference 8 and 8 and the sum is 16

Second example:

Input:

3 1

99 5 85

Output:

10  //85 to 95, so the difference is 10

Third example:

Input:

1 10

9999

Output:

0 // nothing to be change

What I have for now:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    int h = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Entered: " + m);
    System.out.println("Entered: " + h);
    int[] numbers = new int[m];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
//here is my logic: I am changing 1 to 9 
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < 10) {
            numbers[i] = 9;
        }
    else if (numbers[i] > 9 and numbers[i] < 100) {
    numbers[i] = 99;
    }
    }
    sc.close();
```

My logic can work for the first example, but for the second example it won't work. Can you assist me if I am using right logic or is there any easier way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example, 85 changes to 95. Why does your code attempt to change 85 to 99?

Comment: Sorting the array is correct, but you need a custom comparator. Notice that the leftmost, smallest digits should be changed first. If we have `[94, 29, 3]` and `h = 3`, it's clear that you should perform changes as so: `29->99, 3->9, 94->99`. Thus, you need a way to sort the array (or pick from it) in the order `[29, 3, 94]` (left to right). You should also consider `[21, 3, 94]` and `h = 3`; here, it's best to do: `21->91, 91->99, 3->9`. These are two cases I came up with to get you started, but you should consider others as well and reconsider your algorithm/choice of data structures.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur As I said my code works only for the first example. I couldnt write the code to solve all examples, thats why need assistance.

Comment: @wLui155 ohh so hard, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly came up with below solution

```
public static void calculateMax(int m,int h, int[] arr){
     int sum = 0;
     ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
         String stringNum = Integer.toString(arr[i]);
         int num = Integer.parseInt(stringNum.substring(0, 1));
         if(num!=9){
             al.add(Integer.parseInt(("9"+stringNum.substring(1)))-arr[i]);
             continue;
         }
         al.add(0);
     }
     Collections.sort(al);
     int j = al.size()-1;
     for(int i=0;i<h && j>0;i++){
         sum+=al.get(j--);
     }
     System.out.println(sum);
 }
```

Here what I am doing is basically, calculating for each number what we can get as maximum by removing one digit and replacing by 9. And I am storing them in a list. Then we can sort that list and get 'h' largest numbers from stored list, and essentially getting the sum of them and printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Break each input number into its digits times the appropriate power of 10. Sort these by powers of 10 descending, digits ascending. Apply your operation in this order.

E.g., 876, 12, 42 -> 800, 70, 6, 10, 2, 40, 2 -> 800, 10, 40, 70, 2, 2, 6.

Comment: If the custom sort is too much hassle, you probably have few enough different powers of 10 to just use a separate array for 1s, 10s, 100s, etc...